# How to output data from tables with same column names in CodeIgniter?

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

This is my query:

```
$query = $this->db->query('
    SELECT archives.id, archives.signature, type_of_source.description, media_type.description, origin.description 
    FROM archives, type_of_source, media_type, origin                                                             
    WHERE archives.type_of_source_id = type_of_source.id                                                          
    AND type_of_source.media_type_id = media_type.id                                                              
    AND archives.origin_id = origin.id                                                                            
    ORDER BY archives.id ASC
');
```

But how to output the result? This works, but only gets the last description (origin.description):

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo $row['description'];
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo $row['type_of_source.description'];
}
```

Or should I rename the columns (e.g. type_of_source_description)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually has very little to do with CodeIgniter and a lot with how mysql_fetch_assoc provides the query results.

The solution is that you should rename the columns inside the query using `"AS"`, e.g.

```
select type_of_source.description as type_of_source_description, origin.descripotion as origin_descripotion from ....
```

Comment: using postgres, is it still the same?

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't be, "AS" is standard SQL syntax, and I'd wager PHP's pg_* functions work very much like mysql_* ones.

Answer (score 2):

Just alias the columns in the SELECT statement. Do not modify your database. The standard practice is to use aliasing in your SQL statements.

From PostgreSQL's docs for `"SELECT"`:

"Using the clause AS output_name, another name can be specified for an output column."

[PostgreSQL SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/sql-select.html)

Comment: in my case I have a lot of queries without the AS and it would be very painful renaming all. is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not to use it that way instead, you can rename output columns with `AS`.